# vb.net scale a vector3D object

Tags: vb.net, vector, scaling

I have a vector3D object and want to scale it with value -1.0 .
In java i would do

```
 private vector3f vector = new Vector3f(someX,someY,someZ);
 vector.scale(-1.0f);
```

Anyone know how to do this in vb.net?

thanks

Comment: check this: Dim vector As New Vector3f(someX, someY, someZ)
vector.scale(-1F)

Comment: vector3f does not exists in VB.NET. I use vector3d which should be the same. And the vector3d class does not have a methode scale.

Answer (score 0):

private Vector3f vector = new Vector3f(-50.0f, -80.0f, -120.0f);

Comment: I am asking to scale a vector3d in VB.NET. I have no idea what you mean with your answer...